# Como assegurar que meu Plugin não vai matar meu host? (C#/WPF)

Tags: c#

Senhores,

Preciso montar um sistema de Plugin que obedeça alguns requisitos.

1. Garanta isolamento de bibliotecas, por exemplo, O host deve usar MahApps Versão A, e o plugin deve usar versão B.
2. Devo evitar ao Máximo que alguma exceção de Thread ou de sistema, ou algum erro do programador do plugin quebre meu Host.

MAF seria interessante, porém o problema 2 ainda irá continuar. ([Artigo](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/635497/AppDomains-Wont-Protect-Host-From-a-Failing-Plugin))
Implementei o MEF descrito([Artigo](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Simple-Calculator-MEF-1152654e)) pela microsoft, porém quando lanços exceções no plugin, o Host é afetado e fecha.

Qual a melhor opção nesse caso? como devo implementar meu sistema de plugin?